# How to create date(day, week, month) range table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a question about a datetime table in SQL Server.

This is my code. I can make daily

```
SELECT DAYDATE AS BASE_DT

FROM(
        SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(D, NUMBER, '2019-01-01'), 120) AS DAYDATE    
        FROM MASTER..SPT_VALUES WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE TYPE = 'P'
        AND NUMBER <= DATEDIFF(D, '2019-01-01', getdate())
) DATE_TABLE
```

I can make daily column but I don't know how to add week, month column

Like this.

[image]

Please, check this issue. Thank you.

Comment: `WEEK_DT` is always a Sunday?

Comment: If you returned the date as a `date`, and not a `varchar`, applying date logic would be *way* easier.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Yes, right.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). Simple searching will find MANY examples of creating a date (not datetime) table / calendar - like [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;  -- Set first day of week to Monday

SELECT 
 DAYDATE AS BASE_DT 

 -- last day (always a Sunday) of the current week
 , CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DAYDATE), DAYDATE)) AS WEEK_DT 

 -- last day of the current month
 , CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(DAYDATE) - 1900) * 12) 
                                     + MONTH(DAYDATE), -1)) AS MONTH_DT  
FROM (
   SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D, NUMBER, '2019-01-01')) AS DAYDATE    
   FROM MASTER..SPT_VALUES WITH(NOLOCK)
   WHERE TYPE = 'P'
          AND NUMBER <= DATEDIFF(D, '2019-01-01', getdate())
) DATE_TABLE
```

Output:

```
BASE_DT     WEEK_DT     MONTH_DT
----------------------------------
2019-01-01  2019-01-06  2019-01-31
2019-01-02  2019-01-06  2019-01-31
2019-01-03  2019-01-06  2019-01-31
2019-01-04  2019-01-06  2019-01-31
...
2019-02-01  2019-02-03  2019-02-28
2019-02-02  2019-02-03  2019-02-28
2019-02-03  2019-02-03  2019-02-28
...
2021-01-09  2021-01-10  2021-01-31
2021-01-10  2021-01-10  2021-01-31
2021-01-11  2021-01-17  2021-01-31
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEADD and DATEPART, like this:

```
with d as
(
    SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(D, NUMBER, '2019-01-01'), 120) AS DAYDATE    
    FROM MASTER..SPT_VALUES 
    WHERE TYPE = 'P'
    AND NUMBER <= DATEDIFF(D, '2019-01-01', getdate())

)
SELECT DAYDATE AS BASE_DT, 
       dateadd(day,1-datepart(weekday, daydate),daydate) WEEK_DT,
       dateadd(day,1-datepart(day, daydate),daydate) MONTH_DT
FROM d
```